# Why puts inputs it out of the form when I use the form in the table?

Tags: html, laravel

> Error is "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException"

Why puts inputs it  out of the form when I use the form in the table?

**code route**

```php
Route::post('seen_tikuser','ticketController@seen_user')->name('seen_tikuser');
```

**code html blade**

```php
  @if(!empty($datas))          
            @foreach($datas as $item)
            <tr class="trtable">
            <td class="text-center">
                @if($item->seen_user==0)
                <i class="fa fa-eye-slash" style="color:#039403;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                @endif    
                {{$item->id}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{$item->title}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{$item->tproject}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                   @if($item->tproject=='وبسایت') {{$item->damain}}
                   @elseif($item->tproject=='نرم افزار') {{$item->software}}
                   @endif
                </td>

                <td class="text-center">
                    @if($item->status==0) <p style="color: #2196f3; font-size: 16px;"> مشاهده نشده</p> 
                    @elseif($item->status==1) <p style="color:rgb(162, 128, 48); font-size: 16px;">در حال بررسی</p> 
                    @elseif($item->status==2) <p style="color:#5e35b1; font-size: 16px;">در انتظار پاسخ</p> 
                    @elseif($item->status==3) <p style="color: #039403; font-size: 16px;">پاسخ داده شده </p>
                    @elseif($item->status==4) <p style="color:#00bcd4; font-size: 16px;">نگه داشته شده </p> 
                    @elseif($item->status==5) <p style="color: #f06292; font-size: 16px;">پاسخ مشتری </p>
                    @elseif($item->status==6) <p style="color: #e53935; font-size: 16px;">بسته شده </p>

                    @endif
                </td>

                <td class="text-center"></td>



                <form  action="{{route('seen_tikuser')}}" method="post" style="display:none !important">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$item->id}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="seen_user" >
                </form>          

            </tr> 
  @endforeach
  @endif
```

**code ajax**

```js
$.ajaxSetup({ 
    headers: { 
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') 
    } 
}); 
$(document).on('click','.trtable',function(e){ 
   var frmfind = $(this).find('.frmseen'); 
   var data = frmfind.serialize(); 
   var my_url=frmfind.attr('action'); 
   console.log(data); 
   $.ajax({ 
       data: data , 
       type: "POST", 
       url: my_url, 
       success:function(noft){ 
       }, 
       error:function(){ } 
   }); 
});
```

Comment: and what is the rest of that error message, there is more to it than just what you put up

Comment: //code ajax
`<script>

$.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

$(document).on('click','.trtable',function(e){

   
var frmfind=  $(this).find('.frmseen');

    var data=frmfind.serialize();
    var my_url=frmfind.attr('action');
    
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        data: data ,
        type: "POST",
        url: my_url,
        success:function(noft){
        },
        error:function(){
       
        }
    });
 });
</script>`

Comment: add your code to your question not in the comments

Comment: Your question is not clear "Why puts inputs it out of the form when I use the form in the table?" Also what  are you doing with this form?

Comment: input out form and i doing seen ticket user

Comment: what does "input out form" mean? or "seen ticket user"?

Comment: seen ticket user

Comment: no, this is part from code,,,  i used <table></table> <td></td>

Comment: Not in the code you posted though. Place your form inside the `<td></td>` - done

Comment: because this form for save seen tr and hidden